# How to convert data from rows into a specific columns and count them up in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame that looks something like this

| Player | Surface |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | Grass |
| Mike | Concrete |
| Mark | Clay |
| Mike | Clay |
| Mark | Clay |

I want to make another data frame which would like something like this

| Player | Grass | Concrete | Clay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Mark | 0 | 0 | 2 |

I found some old threads and using a reshape package but I couldn't quite figure out how exactly it is used.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `table` from `base R`

```
table(df1)
```

If there are many columns, subset the dataset by selecting those specific columns and then apply the `table`

```
table(df1[c("PLAYER", "SURFACE")])
```

Comment: Oh wow, it was that simple... Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote it as I don't have enough reputation. I will accept it as soon as the cooldown runs out.